# How to log available datasources of HikariCP using javaee with no framework

Tags: java, log4j, hikaricp

i am trying to log my hikariCP but is failing so bad. its my first time trying to use log4j so i dont know where to put my log4j properties. i wanna log something like idle, waiting and used if possible.

Im trying to log it to see whether i have a leakage. im using log4j, javaee with no frameworks and my application server is glassfish.

Comment: Maybe [read this](https://blogs.oracle.com/naman/entry/configure_log4j_for_use_in).  The package for HikariCP logging is going to be ``com.zaxxer.hikari``.

Comment: Thank you very much @brettw, now i know that 1execution gets 11 datasources. what a crappy code i have wrote. HAHAH thanks. BTW a whole new difference topic why do everytime i run my app i see this error : Exception while visiting com/zaxxer/hikari/util/ConcurrentBag.class of size 8899
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.. anyways thank you very much for the help

Comment: it seems that i am wrong. i dont know anything. asdfghjkl :'(. Thanks anyway brettw. HikariCP is really cool :)